# After putting "type_scroll_insensitive" app gui disappered

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdbc, ucanaccess

when I set "ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE" and then when  I run my app I can't see my app's Gui. I am using Ucanaccess driver for my MS access database connection. where is the problem? please help...

here is my code:

```
package javadatabase;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class gui extends Db{

    JFrame fr;
    JLabel fname;
    JLabel lname;
    JLabel age;

    JTextField fntext;
    JTextField lntext;
    JTextField agetext;

    JButton next = new JButton("Next");
    JButton prev = new JButton("Prev");
    JButton first = new JButton("First");
    JButton last = new JButton("Last");



    public gui(){

        frame();
    }

    public void frame(){
        fr = new JFrame();
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setSize(600, 400);
        fr.setVisible(true);

        fname = new JLabel("نوم:  ");
        lname = new JLabel ("تخلص:  ");
        age = new JLabel ("عمر:  ");


        fntext = new JTextField(20);
        lntext = new JTextField(20);
        agetext = new JTextField(20);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(fntext);
        panel.add(fname);
        panel.add(lntext);
        panel.add(lname);
        panel.add(agetext);
        panel.add(age);

        panel.add(next);
        panel.add(prev);
        panel.add(first);
        panel.add(last);


        fr.add(panel);

       try{ 
        rs.next();
        fntext.setText(rs.getString("Fname"));
        lntext.setText(rs.getString("Lname"));
        agetext.setText(rs.getString("Age"));


       }catch(Exception ex){}



    }
}
```

and here is my main class:

```
package javadatabase;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public  class Db {

    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    public Db(){

        connect();
    }


    public void connect(){

        try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://d:\\\\netbeansProjects\\\\db1.accdb");
        st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "select * from Table1";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        }catch(Exception ex) {}
    }     


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Look and feel
            try {UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());}
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
            catch (InstantiationException e) {}
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
            catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {}

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    new Db();
                    new gui();

                }


                }); 


    }

}
```

Comment: You could start by not ignoring all the exceptions silently.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and put a breakpoint on the `new gui();` line.  I am guessing it does not even make it there.

Comment: I just tested UCanAccess v2.0.9.2 and `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` worked fine. Are you using the [latest version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/latest/download) of UCanAccess?

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you, but yes I am using the latest version of UCanAccess v2.0.9.2.

Comment: As   kiheru said, may you print the exception stack trace and post it?

Comment: the program doesn't throw any exception, it's running successfully but I can't see the GUI. And when is remove the "ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE" it appear again.

Comment: How do you know that it does not throw any? The posted code would not show any stack traces, because you catch the possible exceptions, but don't do anything with them. `ex.printStackTrace()` is not a particularly good way to handle exceptions in general, but it would print the stack trace of the exception if one gets thrown.